# how to create a desktop app that can run python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, web-applications

I made a UI using html and css that takes input as file path. What I need is now to enable my python file to take that path name and run the python script on the input file. How can I achieve this? I saw there is something called eel. but I need this app to be distributed so everyone who installs wont have a chrome installed to run in eel. Please provide me with different alternatives to link these two. I'm quite new to web app.

Comment: I think you should use a python backend framework like `Flask` or `Django`, looking detail for there documents.

Comment: But I need this as an offline web app. with a packer and all like eel.

Comment: Wow, I'm now wondering how this can be done, too.

Comment: I do some search and found Eel and CEF Python, but I still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

After some research in Eel and PyInstaller, I found it's quite easy. I tested these instructions in Windows and the example code is from [Eel GitHub](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel).

### Environment Setup

- Install `pipenv` package to setup a virtual environment:

  ```
  $ pip install pipenv
  ```
- Install `eel`, `pyinstaller` to virtual environment:

  ```
  $ pipenv install eel pyinstaller
  ```
- Due to [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1963), we need to install `setuptools==44.1.0`:

  ```
  $ pipenv install setuptools==44.1.0
  ```

### Project Setup

- Here is the file structure:

  ```
  .
  ├── hello.py
  └── web
      ├── favicon.ico
      └── hello.html
  ```
- The content of `hello.py` is:

  ```
  import eel

  eel.init('web')

  @eel.expose
  def say_hello_py(x):
      print('Hello from %s' % x)

  say_hello_py('Python World!')
  eel.say_hello_js('Python World!')

  eel.start('hello.html', size=(300, 200))
  ```
- The content of `hello.html` is:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>Hello, World!</title>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
          eel.expose(say_hello_js);
          function say_hello_js(x) {
              console.log("Hello from " + x);
          }

          say_hello_js("Javascript World!");
          eel.say_hello_py("Javascript World!");

          </script>
      </head>

      <body>
          Hello, World!
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

### Building

- Run following command:

  ```
  $ pipenv run python -m eel hello.py web --onefile --noconsole
  ```
- You will see a `hello.exe` under `dist` folder.

Any more detail you can read the documents of Eel and PyInstaller.

> but I need this app to be distributed so everyone who installs wont have a chrome installed to run in eel.

I think you can use [Edge](https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel#microsoft-edge) in Eel since Edge is installed in every Windows 10, or you may need to use other python GUI framework. Since you write you UI in html and css, I think is may not be possible to distribute without any browser.